# How to tell if a timezone observes daylight saving at any time of the year?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dst

In PHP, you can tell if a given date is during the Daylight Savings Time period by using something like this:

```
$isDST = date("I", $myDate); // 1 or 0
```

The problem is that this only tells you whether that one point in time is in DST. Is there a reliable way to check whether DST is in effect at any time in that timezone?

---

*Edit to clarify:*

- Brisbane, Australia does not observe daylight savings at any time of the year. All year around, it is GMT+10.
- Sydney, Australia does, from October to March when it changes from GMT+10 to GMT+11.

I'm wondering if there would be some existing method, or a way to implement a method which works as such:

```
timezoneDoesDST('Australia/Brisbane');  // false
timezoneDoesDST('Australia/Sydney');  // true
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you rephrase the question somehow? Or maybe give some example? I don't know.

Comment: These aussies are weird (no offence meant) in regard to DST: http://www.bcl.com.au/times-daylight-saving.htm

Comment: Yeah, there's even a political party whose only policy is to introduce daylight savings in South East Queensland...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found a method which works using PHP's DateTimezone class (PHP 5.2+)

```
function timezoneDoesDST($tzId) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);
    $trans = $tz->getTransitions();
    return ((count($trans) && $trans[count($trans) - 1]['ts'] > time()));
}
```

or, if you're running PHP 5.3+

```
function timezoneDoesDST($tzId) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);
    return count($tz->getTransitions(time())) > 0;
}
```

The [`getTransitions()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php) function gives you information about each time the offset changes for a timezone. This includes historical data *(Brisbane had daylight savings in 1916.. who knew?)*, so this function checks if there's an offset change in the future or not.

Comment: For Brisbane - I ran the first 5.2PHP version ✅. Second 5.3PHP example ❌ - reported incorrectly that Brisbane was on DST. I'm on 7.2.8

Comment: It seems like you'd need to check `count($tz->getTransitions(time())) > 1`, because I think there is always 1 entry.

Edit: @Simon I just read comment above mine more closely, I think my answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 15):

Actually nickf method didn't works for me so I reworked it a little ...

```
/**
* Finds wherever a TZ is experimenting dst or not
* @author hertzel Armengol <emudojo @ gmail.com>
* @params string TimeZone -> US/Pacific for example
*
*/
function timezoneExhibitsDST($tzId) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);
    $date = new DateTime("now",$tz);  
    $trans = $tz->getTransitions();
    foreach ($trans as $k => $t) 
      if ($t["ts"] > $date->format('U')) {
          return $trans[$k-1]['isdst'];    
    }
}

// Usage  

var_dump(timezoneExhibitsDST("US/Pacific")); --> prints false
var_dump(timezoneExhibitsDST("Europe/London")); --> prints false
var_dump(timezoneExhibitsDST("America/Chicago")); --> prints false
```

same function call will return true in 1 month (March) hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

[DateTimeZone::getTransitions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php) might help.

You could probably wing it:

```
$hasDst = date("I", strtotime('June 1')) !== date("I", strtotime('Jan 1'));
```

Otherwise you'd need to parse the text-based [zoneinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo#File_formats) data files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but since almost every country that observes DST changes its time for an entire season or two, you could try to test 4 points during any given year.

For example, test `date("I", $date)` for 2009/01/01, 2009/04/01, 2009/07/01 and 2009/10/01. If that timezone falls into DST, then at least one of those dates will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

date has to be on the user/server timezone for it to work, and you can't use a range with date as you do with getTransitions