# gmdata in php not working properly

Tags: php

It's a simple question..but drive me 2 madness.
the result of this simple line of code:

```
echo gmdate('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

... must output GMT time but it get it minus 1 hour!!!!!
So why??

Comment: `2011/05/03 14:17:21` in my computer, which is the correct value. What are you getting?

Comment: because you haven't read the manual!

Answer (score 1):

Greenwich Mean Time has **no** "Summer Time" or "**Daylight Saving Time**" so depending on the season of the year these statements may produce the same or different output.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); 
echo gmdate('c'); 
echo date('c');
```

-- from the PHP manual (so, in addtion to the answer you get a clear RTM ;)

More information about [timezones and daylight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586552/how-to-tell-if-a-timezone-observes-daylight-saving-at-any-time-of-the-year) saving on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the output of your script with:

- http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx

If it's wrong, the computer where you run the code is probably misconfigured.

Comment: Thank u, it wasn't already, I modified it becuz Egypt canceled DST:D