# How to find summertime adjustment, for a given date and timezone, in R?

Tags: php, r, timezone, dst

In PHP (since 5.2.0) I can write this code:

```
//$t is timestamp of day I want to look at
$tz=new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$transition = $tz->getTransitions($t,$t);
if(!$transition || count($transition)==0)throw new Exception("Bad timezone")
$offset=$transition[0]['offset'];   //This is seconds ahead of GMT.
      //I.e. -14400 in summer, -18000 in winter.
```

I nearly cried with joy when I discovered this class/idiom; but is there a way to do the same thing in R? Or do I have to resort to what I used to do in PHP, which was hard-code an array of summertime start/end dates for each timezone I need to consider?

(BTW, for more on the PHP code, see: [How to tell if a timezone observes daylight saving at any time of the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586552/how-to-tell-if-a-timezone-observes-daylight-saving-at-any-time-of-the-year) )

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies (they were the same; I gave the tick to Oscar simply as I was already using POSIXlt). I realized I could have been doing this in PHP all along too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `as.POSIXct` and `as.POSIXlt` you can get this information. For example:

```
tz = 'Europe/Madrid'
d1 <- as.POSIXct('2010-01-01 12:00:00',  tz = tz)
as.POSIXlt(d1)$isdst ## 0 since it's not DST
```

If you need the difference from UTC:

```
d0 <- as.POSIXct(format(d1,  tz = 'UTC'),  tz = tz)
as.numeric(d1 - d0) ## 1 hour
```

The same for another day:

```
d2 <- as.POSIXct('2010-07-01 12:00:00',  tz = tz)
as.POSIXlt(d2)$isdst ## 1 since it is DST
d0 <- as.POSIXct(format1(d2,  tz = 'UTC'),  tz = tz)
as.numeric(d2 - d0) ## 2 hour
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build two time objects, for the same date and time, one in the desired time zone, the other in GMT, and look at their difference.

```
# Winter: London uses GMT
> ISOdatetime(2012, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, "Europe/London") - 
  ISOdatetime(2012, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, "GMT")
Time difference of 0 secs

# Summer: London uses GMT+1
> ISOdatetime(2012, 08, 01, 00, 00, 00, "Europe/London") - 
  ISOdatetime(2012, 08, 01, 00, 00, 00, "GMT")
Time difference of -1 hours
```