# Calculate if DST active for a given timestamp and offset

Tags: php, timezone, dst

Given a unix timestamp and timezone offset relative to UTC (e.g. -5), is it possible to calculate if DST is active?

I can do something like:

```
<?php
  echo 'DST enabled? ' . date('I', 1345731453) ."<br>"; 
?>
```

But I cannot see how to pass in an offset or a TimeZone.

Im guessing also that there is a difference between the timezone and the offset, given that specific countries support DST?

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Yes indeed, a UTC offset doesn't say anything about which country it is, which means you cannot really determine the DST setting.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have found my solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586552/how-to-tell-if-a-timezone-observes-daylight-saving-at-any-time-of-the-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you need to start with date and tz to determine offset.

in 5.3+ you can get transitions for start/end period, so you can just use your timestamp for both, something like this:

```
$inputTime = $your_unix_timestamp;
$inputTZ = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'); 

$transitions = $inputTZ->getTransitions($inputTime,$inputTime); 
$offset = $transitions[0]['offset'];
```

`$offset` is the DST offset at the time in question

Comment: Small warning: in your example $offset will hold the complete offset towards GMT+0, not just the amount that DST adds to it.
So in this case it works, because you're using London as your timezone. But if you were to use Athens (GMT+3 in the summer), $offset would 10800 (3 hours), not 3600 (the 1 hour DST offset)  
I'm still working on this myself, but I think the best way to see if DST is *active*, is using DateTime's format('I').

Comment: Thanx this simplified some thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Get the timezone with:

```
$old_zone = ini_get('date.timezone');
```

Change it to the one you want:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Brussels');
```

Revert back:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', $old_zone);
```

The PHP timestamp is always UTC. Depending on your timezone setting it determine what time to show.